# Aligning Images Below Text using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

I'm trying to align three images found in a row that are in three separate columns at and equal height to each other. The images are sized 348 x 628 but the text above them pushes them down or up depending on the amount of text above them. How do I align them regardless of the text above them? I'm also trying to make sure that the text above and the picture below are in the same column for responsive development purposes.

Here's what I have:

```
<div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div style="position: relative;">
                   <img style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;" src="{% "number1.png" %}" alt=""/>
                    <span style="display: block; overflow: hidden;">Click the "Sign-In" button</span>
                    <img src="{% static "image1.png" %}" alt="" style="position: absolute;">
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div style="position:relative"> 
                    <img style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;" src="{% "number2.png" %}" alt=""/>
                    <span style="display: block; overflow: hidden">After Signing into your account, please click on the settings button</span>
                    <img src="{% static "image2.png" %}" alt="" style="position: absolute;">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div>
                    <img style="float:left; margin-right: 10px;" src="{% static "number3.png" %}" alt=""/>
                    <span style="overflow: hidden;">Select "Wifi"</span>
                    <img src="{% static "image3.png" %}" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the `figure-tag` in HTML? You can easily create images with a description. Also, the CSS is only there to center the `figure` and to show the border.

Here's an document made by w3Schools: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_figure.asp

Here's the code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

figure {
  width: 300px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <figcaption>Above Image</figcaption>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
</figure>

<figure>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
  <figcaption>Below Image</figcaption>
</figure>
```

You can also make a responsive Image Gallery with flexbox:

```css
#gallery {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

figure {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="gallery">

  <figure>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    <figcaption>Image Description</figcaption>
  </figure>
  
  <figure>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    <figcaption>Image Description</figcaption>
  </figure>
  
  <figure>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    <figcaption>Image Description</figcaption>
  </figure>
  
  <figure>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    <figcaption>Image Description</figcaption>
  </figure>
  
  <figure>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    <figcaption>Image Description</figcaption>
  </figure>
  
  <figure>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    <figcaption>Image Description</figcaption>
  </figure>
  
  <figure>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    <figcaption>Image Description</figcaption>
  </figure>
  
  <figure>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    <figcaption>Image Description</figcaption>
  </figure>
  
  <figure>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    <figcaption>Image Description</figcaption>
  </figure>
  
  <figure>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    <figcaption>Image Description</figcaption>
  </figure>
  
  <figure>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    <figcaption>Image Description</figcaption>
  </figure>
  
  <figure>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    <figcaption>Image Description</figcaption>
  </figure>
  
  <figure>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    <figcaption>Image Description</figcaption>
  </figure>
  
  <figure>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    <figcaption>Image Description</figcaption>
  </figure>
  
  <figure>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    <figcaption>Image Description</figcaption>
  </figure>
  
  <figure>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    <figcaption>Image Description</figcaption>
  </figure>

</div>
```